# Sort ArrayList in reverse order in Java

Tags: java

I am new to the android studio. I want sort this ordersList in reverse order what should I do?

```
Collections.sort(ordersLists, new Comparator <OrdersList> () {
    @Override
    public int compare(OrdersList ordersList, OrdersList t1) {
        return ordersList.getOrderID().compareToIgnoreCase(t1.getOrderID());
    }
});
```

Comment: Nothing to do with the IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by multiplying the result with `-1` e.g.

```
Collections.sort(ordersLists, new Comparator <OrdersList> () {
    @Override
    public int compare(OrdersList ordersList, OrdersList t1) {
        return ordersList.getOrderID().compareToIgnoreCase(t1.getOrderID()) * -1;
    }
});
```

Comment: Or just putting a `-` sign before the expression.

Comment: What about `t1.getOrderID().compareToIgnoreCase(ordersList.getOrderID())` ?

Comment: this code won't put a -0 thou

Comment: This worked for me thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use the comparator chain and [`reversed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed--):

```
Collections.sort(
    Comparator.comparing(OrderList::getOrderID, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
              .reversed());
```

Comment: Minor nit: this doesn't ignore case.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov thanks, added `CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`

Answer (score 0):

Just call [`.reversed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed--) on your `Comparator`.